# Ansible: check if variable equals string

Tags: variables, conditional-statements, ansible

I have an ansible variable passed in on the command line as such:

```
ansible-playbook -e environment=staging ansible/make_server.yml
```

I want to load in some variables in my role dependeing on the value of environment. I have tried a lot of different methods such as:

```
- include_vars: staging_vars.yml
  when: environment | staging
```

and

```
- include_vars: staging_vars.yml
  when: "{{environment}} == "staging"
```

and

```
- include_vars: staging_vars.yml
  when: "{{environment}} | match('staging')"
```

but nothing seems to work. How do I do this?

Details:

- I am using ansible 1.7.2

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Be careful with a variable called `environment`, it can cause problems because Ansible uses it internally. I can't remember if it's in the docs, but here's a mailing list thread:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/fP0hX2Za4I0

We use a variable called `stage`.

It looks like you'll end up with a bunch of these in a row:

```
- include_vars: testing_vars.yml
  when: stage == "testing"
- include_vars: staging_vars.yml
  when: stage == "staging"
- include_vars: production_vars.yml
  when: stage == "production"
```

But you could also just include your environment:

```
- include_vars: "{{ stage }}_vars.yml"
```

Or, use the `vars_files` on a playbook level:

```
vars_files:
  - vars/{{ stage }}_vars.yml
```

Comment: Environment works, but environment as you say is used internally and Ansible do say in the docs not to use it.  Case is important  :)